# Textformfield input text position not equal with icon flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have textformfield that have icon, but the input text position not equal with the icon i have somehow

how do i fix this?

code i tried

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'Email',
                fillColor: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.https),
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'Password',
                fillColor: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opMHT.jpg)

[to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWo1.jpg)

Comment: Hi Karin, can you show the relevant code you have done so far?

Comment: hello michael, i edited my question for the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow below approach :

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
```

Please use content padding inside InputDecoration and also try to put TextFormField inside container for better alignment.

Comment: thank you amit, not what i expected but it can give what i wanted

Comment: Thank You! It sorted: dart:ui/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 1372: '<optimized out>': is not true Error.